# Fragment flashes after removal and animation ends

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, material-design

I've been trying to get a fragment to be inserted and removed from my activity with a circular reveal animation. I found this demo repo [here](https://github.com/ferdy182/Android-CircularRevealFragment) that does exactly this. The only change I made was to have the fragment removed on a button click, instead of the fragment touched listener.

The problem is, after removal using the button, when the animation ends, I see the fragment flash for a second. The flash doesnt happen if I'm removing the fragment using the onTouch listener: [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MBx6kLKZM0)

A few observations:
- If I run the code on my mobile device, then the flash only happens if I'm removing the fragment using the button. No flash occurs when onFragmentTouch is called.
- If I'm running this on the emulator, then I can see it flash on both, the button press and the fragment touch.

To simplify things, my onFragmentTouch listener is simply calling a function `remove` that actually removes the fragment. This same function is also called by the button, in its XML.
I can't understand why this is happening. Code for reference.

Add fragment, within main activity:

```
public void addFragment(View v)
    {
        int randomColor =
                Color.argb(255, (int)(Math.random() * 255), (int)(Math.random() * 255), (int)(Math.random() * 255));
        mfragment = CircularRevealingFragment.newInstance(20, 20, randomColor);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mfragment).commit();
    }
```

Function to remove fragment, also within main activity:

```
public void remove(View v){
        Animator unreveal = mfragment.prepareUnrevealAnimator(0, 0);
        unreveal.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mfragment).commit();
            }
            //hiding other overridden function.
        });
        unreveal.start();
    }
```

The CircularRevealingFragment is pretty straightforward, with mostly everything being the same as in that github project. The unreveal animator:

```
public Animator prepareUnrevealAnimator(float cx, float cy)
    {
        int radius = getEnclosingCircleRadius(getView(), (int)cx, (int)cy);
        Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(getView(), (int) cx, (int) cy, radius, 0);
        anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2f));
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        return anim;
    }
```

Can anyone explain the behavior shown in the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the main problem is that commited `FragmentTransaction` executes asynchronously. If you want to immediately executing use `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()`.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it. I had found a workaround if for some reason this solution doesn't work for others: I made the parent layout of the fragment invisible right after the animation ended, and before I removed the fragment. Kind of a hack, but also works. This would be a better solution though. Thanks!